# PHP Resize Image to a specified size

Tags: php, image-resizing

Is it possible to resize an image in PHP, to a specified size in Kilobytes, with large images?

Example: [IMGonline.com.ua](https://www.imgonline.com.ua/eng/compress-image-size.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely resize to a certain size using resize so if you know a certain number of pixels will be within that size you could set a pixel size. I've used `100x100` for reference.

```
$resize = new ResizeImage('image.png');
$resize->resizeTo(100, 100, 'exact');
$resize->saveImage('/resized/image.png');
```

Using this theory you could take the same approach and if an image is already that size or below you could resize it.

```
if ($file_size < 5000) {
 $resize = new ResizeImage('image.png');
 $resize->resizeTo(100, 100, 'exact');
 $resize->saveImage('/resized/image.png');
} else {
    // Error
}
```

So you could run it like this

```
// Upload Image
  // Resize image
 $resize = new ResizeImage('image.png');
 $resize->resizeTo(100, 100, 'exact');
 $resize->saveImage('/resized/image.png');
// Save image
// Open saved image
// Check image size
// Confirm or resize progressively smaller.
```

Hopefully the resize property is of some use. You've provided no code in your question but I think the best approach would be to check the size and save if it's fine then if not you would resize again and check again. Obviously you'd have to do this until it was at the correct size so execution time could take longer. I can't think of a direct way to compress the image with a php function unless you compressed the images instead of resizing them.

Comment: Hi... thanks for your response... but I would just like to decrease the image quality so that it gets smaller, for example .. convert an image from 2mb to 300kb specifically.